# Binance websocket ping/pong frame

Tags: python, websocket, ping, binance

I'm working with Binance API, specifically with websocket endpoint, to receive updats to the best bid or ask's price or quantity in real-time for a specified symbol using Python and [websocket-client](https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/) library. Everything works just fine, until a ping frame is received from the Binance, it fails with code 1008 and then connections is closed. Here is my code:

```
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
        self.SOCKET_URL,
        on_message=_on_message,
        on_open=_on_open,
        on_error=_on_error,
        on_close=_on_close,
        on_ping=_on_ping,
)
```

```
def _reconnect(self, ws: websocket.WebSocketApp):
    if ws.sock is not None:
        if ws.sock.connected:
            return
        else:
            ws.close()

    self.clear_database()

    ws.run_forever(http_proxy_port=8080, ping_interval=60)
    if ws.sock is not None and ws.sock.connected:
        return

    logger.info("[SOCKET Close] %s provider. Unable to reconnect, need to do it manually",
                self.provider.name)
    ws.close()

def _on_error(self, ws, error):
    self._reconnect(ws)

    logger.info('[SOCKET Err] %s provider: %s', self.provider.name, error)

def _on_close(self, ws, _, close_msg):
    logger.info("[SOCKET Close] %s provider: %s. Code %s", self.provider.name, close_msg, _)

    self._reconnect(ws)

def _on_ping(self, ws, *_):
    ws.send(websocket.ABNF.OPCODE_PING)
```

In on_ping i send websocket.ABNF.OPCODE_PING because I saw it in the websocket-client library source code.

I tried to remove on_ping handler from WebsocketApp initialization, hoping that library takes care of the incoming ping messages itself - no luck. Also setting `ping_interval` didn't help. I also tried to send different data inside `on_ping` handler, such as:

```
ws.send('PING')
```

or just reflect incoming message like this

```
def _on_ping(self, ws, *_):
    ws.send(*_)
```

Comment: dont know jack about the topic but isnt a reply to PING a PONG ?

Comment: at least https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#pings_and_pongs_the_heartbeat_of_websockets says  `When you get a ping, send back a pong with the exact same Payload `

Comment: maybe i send it wrong? Have you ever done something like that before?